# XGBoost on Spark crashes with SIGSEV

Tags: scala, apache-spark, xgboost, databricks, azure-databricks

I use Scala in Azure Databricks with the following setup:

- 5x worker node (`28.0 GB Memory, 8 Cores, 1.5 DBU`)
- 1x driver (`14.0 GB Memory, 4 Cores, 0.75 DBU`)

I have a Spark Dataframe with 760k rows with two columns:

1. label (`Double`)
2. features (`SparseVector` of length `84224` each)

I want to use `XGBoost` on my Dataframe, to train the regression model:

```
val params = Map(
  "objective" -> "reg:linear",
  "max_depth" -> 6,
  "eval_metric" -> "rmse"
)
var model = new XGBoostRegressor(params)
  .setFeaturesCol("features")
  .setLabelCol("label")
  .setTreeMethod("approx")
  .setNumRound(20)
  .setNumEarlyStoppingRounds(3)
  .setUseExternalMemory(true)
  .setMaxDepth(6)
  .setNumWorkers(10)

val trainedModel = model.fit(trainSample)
```

After launching, I get the following error:

> SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f62a9d33e0e, pid=3954,
>   tid=0x00007f62c88db700

**What I've tried so far:**

When I set `numWorkers` to `1`, the training starts, but obviously runs really slow, which I believe is no the way it should be used.

The documentation here: https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/external_memory.html and here: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/mllib/third-party-libraries.html#xgboost does not help at all with my case.

**My questions are:**

1. Is it possible to run XGBoost on Dataset that is bigger than memory of each individual worker? (I assume that it's YES, but correct me if I'm wrong)
2. How to use External Memory properly, so that when I take even bigger dataset XGBoost will do the training?
3. Is partitioning of the input Dataframe impacting the training somehow?

Comment: Do you have access to the console of the driver??

Comment: I am able to access stdout, stderr and log4j output of the driver